# Web Platform Installer - ProductId NETFramework4 not found

Tags: feed, runtime-error, web-platform-installer

After setting a custom feed in Web Platform Installer when trying to set up mojoPortal the program crashed with the error `ProductId NETFramework4 not found`:

[image]

When trying to launch the program again the same error happened upon launch.

I tried re-installing the program but the problem remained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix that worked for me was to delete the configuration file `webpi.preferences` found in the folder:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer
```

To get there you can:

1. Press: <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type: %APPDATA% <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. And then navigate to the folder mentioned above and delete the preferences file.